# How can I show the appropriate user given the users ID when *ngFor'ing another list? (Angular 6)

Tags: angular, typescript

I am getting a list of postings from [here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) via a http-service.

Each element contains a field called "userId", which is a reference to a user ([here](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users)).

**Now, my question is:** If i want to show posts with not just the userId's, but with usernames and so forth as well, how would I go about doing it?

**My idea was:** Retrieve all the users as well and do a small lookup inside the template. (I am not sure how to do this though)

Thank you for any help in advance.

Comment: I would suggest against doing this in the front-end, and would perform any joins etc in the backend

Answer (score 0):

You could, as you suggest, retrieve all of the users first, and keep them in memory on the client side (in the Angular app), and then just look up the user for each post.

That would be fine for this particular use case (there are only 10 users), but would not be reasonable in a more likely real-world scenario where the is a large number of users.

Similarly, in a real-world scenario, you wouldn't want to retrieve all of the posts either, for the same reason - there could be an essentially unlimited number of posts, and you wouldn't be able to hold them all in memory, or to show them all on the screen, without crashing the user's browser.

So, in a "real" app, firstly, you'd only show a relatively small number of posts at a time, e.g. the most recent 100 or so posts, the most recent x number of posts for a particular user, etc. You would have to arrange for "paging" the results between the server and the client to show more than that.

Back to your original question, I would suggest one of two things:

If you control the API, arrange for the user name (and any other related info) to be returned along with each post.

If you don't control the API, then for the "page" of posts that you are showing, collect up all of the unique userIds, and make a request to the server to retrieve user info for those ids. The best situation would be if you can make one "batch" request with the list of user ids. If that API doesn't exist, you'd have to make one API call per user id.

Then you can match up the posts to the users, but you only have to deal with the number of users for the page of posts that you are showing, rather than all users.